# Is this workaround used by my book to find the value of $1/0$ legitimate?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I was doing a physics problem and found that I reached an interesting equation:-

[image: Question]

To cross the river directly from A to B (making a right angle with the velocity of the stream), how must the fisherman direct his/her boat's motion? Find the angle ($\alpha$) between the velocity vector of the stream and the resultant velocity vector of the boat. The magnitude of the velocity of the boat is $v=2.778ms^{-1}$ and that of the stream is $u=1.3889ms^{-1}$.

Solution:

We know from the [Parallelogram law of addition of vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law):

$$\tan\theta=\frac{Qsin\alpha}{P+Qcos\alpha}$$

Similarly,

$$\tan(90^{\circ})=\frac{v\sin\alpha}{u+v\cos\alpha}$$

$$\implies\frac{\sin(90^{\circ})}{\cos(90^{\circ})}=\frac{v\sin\alpha}{u+v\cos\alpha}$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{0}=\frac{v\sin\alpha}{u+v\cos\alpha}$$

$$\implies{u+v\cos\alpha}=0$$

Now, isn't $\;\dfrac10\;$ undefined? How is cross-multiplication valid here? I'm very confused.

Comment: it is not valid however as any fraction with finite numerator and denominator approaches infinity, the denominator must approach $0$

Comment: That representation of $\tan 90$ is not valid (mathematically, I won't speak for physicists) and the cross-multiplication is also invalid.  What you *could* rigorously say is that since $\tan \theta$ grows without bound as $\theta \rightarrow 90^\circ$ and $\sin \alpha$ is bounded, either $v+v \cos \alpha$ must shrink to $0$ or $u$ grows without bound.  Assuming you have constraints on $u$ you're then (mostly) in the position of your last line

Comment: You're not confused;  you're correct.  Cross multiplication is not legitimate here.  And writing $1/0$ is meaningless.  What we do know is that as the argument of the tangent function appoaches $90$ degrees from the left, the term on the right-hand side tends to $\infty$.  The only way for this to happen is that the denominator tends to $0$ since the speed $u$ is bounded by the speed of light.

Comment: One line answer: $\tan 90$ is not $\frac{1}{0}$ I am confused whether to write this as a answer as it is or rather leave it a comment

Comment: @postmortes ya I also thought same so rather left it as a comment

Comment: $\tan(90^{\circ})\ $ has no meaning as $\ \tan(x)\ $ is undefined at $\ x=90^\circ.$ Or another way of saying this is that $90^\circ\ $ is not in the domain of $\ \tan(x).$ In short, don't write $\ \tan 90^\circ.$

Comment: Did you arrive at tan(90) through some limiting process?  If so, try to rewrite the equation without the tangent function in such a way that the limit is finite.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I did not arrive at tan(90) through some limiting process. I just inputted the value into the formula.

Comment: @postmortes I edited the question, could you please look into it again?

Comment: Should I edit in the exact physics problem as well to help you understand better? It is a fairly simple question.

Comment: @postmortes:  I think that should be the answer.  I suspect a bit earlier we have $\tan(\beta)=\frac{u\sin\alpha}{v+u\cos\alpha}$ as a way of computing $\beta$ from $\alpha$.  We then look for where the calculation blows up, which is often interesting in physics.  It is then sloppy.  We could write it in terms of the limit as $\beta \to 90^\circ$ and get the same result.

Comment: I got my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4175646/768162

Comment: @postmortes yes, it does. Thanks!